# $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop freezing the page scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an app where I have added the functionality to scroll user to the top if user clicks on status bar and in order to achieve that I have used the following code

```
.run(["$ionicScrollDelegate", "$ionicPlatform", "$timeout", function($ionicScrollDelegate, $ionicPlatform, $timeout) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {     
            if (window.cordova && ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
                window.addEventListener("statusTap", function() {
                    $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop([true]);
                });
            }
        });
    }])
```

When I click the status bar then the code works as expected but after that it does not allow me to scroll the pages manually and it stucks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using android phone to do a test. If android I'm pretty sure there have a bug by using animation to do auto-scroll. Have you try to remove the animation by delete 'true' value on the function? Ex:

```
$ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop(true);
```

to

```
$ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop();
```

Try It.. hope it helps you. IOS is working fine with animation scroll but not for android. So sad.. :(

UPDATE (SOLUTION):

Okay I found the solution.. It seem we need to set 'jsScrolling: true' instead of by default is 'jsScrolling: false' for android.

Please modified/edit this on 'ionic-angular.js'

Hope it helps others :)

Comment: Why would you edit this in the ionic files when you can set it with a global config `$ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(true);`?

Comment: Oops.. yeah, you're right.. we also can set on global config. But just in case need specific setting for devices...  By the way.. many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop();
```

This is the correct usage, Reference: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicScrollDelegate/

**An example**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <ion-content delegate-handle="mainScroll">
  <button ng-click="scrollMainToTop()">
   Scroll content to top!
  </button>
  </ion-content>
</body>
```

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $ionicScrollDelegate) {
  $scope.scrollMainToTop = function() {
   $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('mainScroll').scrollTop();
  };
 }
```